# How to apply a formula down a column for several columns

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I would like to autofill several columns with a formula.  Since the columns are evenly spaced, I'd like to use a loop to accomplish this.  How can I alter the following code to loop through filling four columns with the formula shown:

```
j = 4
Do Until j = 14
    Cells(2, j).Select
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Intersect(.Range("D2").CurrentRegion, .Range("D:D")).Formula = "=(C2/B2)*60"
    End With
j = j + 2
Loop
```

The code above works great for column D, but I need to apply it to columns D,F,H,and J.  I also need C2 in the formula to change to C2,E2,G2, and I2 corresponding with the afformentioned D,F,H and J. The point is to use the loop structure included above, unless that's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop. Try below code 
Similarly you can apply to other columns.

```
Sub test()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D14").Formula = "=IF(RC[-2]="""","""",(RC[-1]/RC[-2])*60)"
End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify, the length of the column will vary in each execution of the program, and the looping through j was meant for hopping from column to column.  Also, the B2 in the formula will always be column B.  Basically the formula serves as a unit conversion, so I need to include B in every conversion, but their are four columns of data that need to be converted.

Unfortunately, this didn't work for me.  I've actually got it to work with a Select Case, but I'd rather use something more compact.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Select Case is an option, although it does take up some space :

```
j = 4
Do Until j = 12
    Cells(2, j).Select
    Select Case j
        Case 4
            With Sheets("Sheet1")
            Intersect(.Range("D2").CurrentRegion, .Range("D2:D" & DataPointCount)).Formula = "=(C2/B2)*60"
            End With
        Case 6
            With Sheets("Sheet1")
            Intersect(.Range("F2").CurrentRegion, .Range("F2:F" & DataPointCount)).Formula = "=(E2/B2)*60"
            End With
        Case 8
            With Sheets("Sheet1")
            Intersect(.Range("H2").CurrentRegion, .Range("H2:H" & DataPointCount)).Formula = "=(G2/B2)*60"
            End With
        Case 10
            With Sheets("Sheet1")
            Intersect(.Range("J2").CurrentRegion, .Range("J2:J" & DataPointCount)).Formula = "=(I2/B2)*60"
            End With
    End Select
j = j + 2
Loop
```